# Programmatically added Views in TableLayout / TableRow have a height and width of 0

Tags: android, layout

I have a TableLayout in my app, which I need to define and add programmatically, as it builds upon the output of an SQL query. Basically, the result should look similar to a timetable (7 columns for each day in a week, multiple rows for different timeslots per day). For the cells/timeslots, I just need ordinary views with a certain background colour.

The problem is, that all views end up with a height and width of 0, although defined otherwise. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tableLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tableLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.myOtherLayout);
tableLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
table.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
table.setMinimumHeight(PixelConverter.pxToSp(this, 240));

// get availability table data
int[][] tableData = getTableData(...);

if (availability != null) { 
    // init array of tablerows, which represent one line each for every timeslot
    for (int timeSlot = 0; timeSlot < 12; h++) {
        // init row
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        newRow.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, // width
            10)); // height
        newRow.setMinimumHeight(10);

        // create 7 views in each row - one for each day in a week
        for (int day = 0; day < 7; d++) {
            View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                10, // TODO width
                10)); // height
            v.setMinimumWidth(10);
            v.setMinimumHeight(10);

            int cellHue = tableData[day][timeSlot];
            if (cellHue >= 0) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(new float[] { cellHue, 100, 100 }));
            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }

            // add view to tablerow
            newRow.addView(v, day);
        }

        table.addView(newRow, timeSlot);
    }       
}

table.setId(R.id.my_table_id);
mainLayout.addView(table, tableLayout);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered a similar issue - the problem appears to be with the choice of type of `LayoutParams` used after inflating your views.  Particularly, the following is probably the root of your problem:

```
View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            10, // TODO width
            10)); // height
```

I'd suggest that you try:

```
View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            10, // TODO width
            10)); // height
```

The key is that you apparently should specify the *type of the parent view* when using `LayoutParams`, rather than the type of the view that you're setting them on.  Note that in this case, you'll probably need to specify `TableLayout.LayoutParams` when calling `setLayoutParams` on your row, too.

I don't know how well documented this is - I noticed it mentioned on an arbitrary blog I'd found (lost the link now, alas) and I haven't had chance to go back to the official documention yet, but presumably it's there somewhere... :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, glancing at the doc for LInearLayout: "Set the layout parameters associated with this view. These supply parameters to the **parent** of this view specifying how it should be arranged. There are many subclasses of ViewGroup.LayoutParams, and these correspond to the different subclasses of ViewGroup that are responsible for arranging their children."

Comment: Yes, that worked - thanks Matt ! Actually worked around it in different ways, but I could swear I saw an official Google tutorial taking the "wrong" LayoutParams (therefore thought they are more or less interchangable).

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty new to Android and I've seen *plenty* of examples knocking about using the wrong LayoutParams.  Ah well, got there in the end :)